# Share a native library across two applications

Tags: android, service

Presently in my Android system, I have developed a native library to communicate
with a connected media device over linux driver and we are accessing it from an 
apk application via the Java native interface. This has been working fine till 
now.

But we also have another application which needs to access the same native library
in parallel with the first application. As expected, because of the different data 
section for the linked native library in the new application this approach is not 
working.

To subvert this, we though of writing a new service/application which will be linked
with the native library and other applications access the APIs using binder calls to 
this new service/application.

My question is:

1. Is this new approach feasible? Can someone help me with a better approach.
2. If yes, then we also need to return buffers in the API and some of the APIs are 
   callbacks. Can these types of functions be handled using the binder interface?

Thanks,
Ashutosh

Answer (score 0):

Build an external library in a jar that provides the higher level API which in turn accesses the native library. Then use this jar library as any other lib. You may have to check how to put the .so file into the jar file to have a single library file.

Comment: Can the .so file be shared between more than two apps? For example, how do I make any number apps share a common .so file without using external storage? Can you provide more details in your answer?

Comment: This is worth a new question. Post it! For now: No, not by just putting the .so file on the application's data folder on device.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the service approach is exactly how opencv achieves this.... specifically, OpenCV has a manager in thr app store. You can develop an app that implements BaseLoaderCallback, which gets the .so library from this manager. Behind the scenes, this uses a Service, ServiveConnection, and aidl to get the library... if memory serves me right.

Update...

Now that i think about it, i think OpenCV manager might just be passing the path to the library, which can then be loaded with the System.load command, which accepts the library path.